# Add signal at graphics window through CAPL scripting

Tags: capl

I want to know the  method  through which I can add the signal to the graphics window through CAPL Scripting.So that during the execution of my testcases ,at graphics window signal related to only respective testcase should be present.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is currently no way to interact with the UI from a CAPL script (i.e. you only have direct access to Signals/Messages and Environment Variables). Indirectly, you might be able to write a CAPL-DLL which uses COM automation to interact with the CANoe UI).

---

**Edit (additional information)**
I did a bit more research and apparently there is no COM object or method which allows access to the Graphics window. There is a LoggingCollection object, but that only allows access to the trace logging functionality.

I generally use Python for COM Automation (as opposed to the VB examples available in CANoe help) and I checked the properties of the Configuration.OnlineSetup object and it has a GraphicCollection property but it seems like the object is not yet implemented.

Based on personal experience, I know that Vector has excellent support, you can always try to get in touch with them for more help.